# Library to search unstructured text on Android

Tags: android, full-text-search

I'm writing an Android app where I need to quickly search through a large amount of text. The text is fixed; I would like to compute the indexes off-line and ship them with the app. Here are the requirements for the search library (numbers 1-5 are critical):

1. Must support Unicode character set.
2. Searches need to find arbitrary substrings within the text (not just terms or term prefixes).
3. The search needs to return all matches.
4. The library should be as lightweight as possible. In particular, it should be possible to strip out the indexing (and other) parts of the library and package the app with only the search API.
5. The library license must permit it to be used in a proprietary combined work.
6. There is no need for morphological analysis (stemming) or stop-word handling.
7. Wildcard and/or regular expression search would be nice to have, but not required.
8. Proximity search would also be nice.
9. Likewise boolean search.

FTS3 (which comes with SQLite) is great with respect to requirement 4, but unfortunately won't satisfy requirement 2. (It can find term prefixes but not suffixes—a search for "eat" can find "eats" but not "seat".)

I've looked at a number of libraries, including Lucene, Minion, and egothor. They all seem loaded down with great features that I don't need. I also am under the impression (although this may be wrong) that it would be hard to partition these libraries and just package up the search API. (I've also heard that it's hard to get Lucene to work on Android because it relies on java.rmi, which Android's Java does not include.)

Does anyone know of a library that does what I need (or could be adapted)? I'm not averse to porting the search API from another language into Java if the library otherwise meets the requirements.

Comment: Maybe custom tokenizer for SQLite FTS3 would be of use for you?

Comment: @JuozasKontvainis - I looked at that first. There are two problems. First, a custom tokenizer can only be used to change what is considered a token; it can't change the basic operation of FTS3. From what I have read, no form of tokenizing is going to address the fundamental limitation of token-based indexing: it can be used to find token prefixes, but not suffixes. Second, I don't know that it's even possible to use a custom tokenizer in Android's version of SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Lucy](http://lucy.apache.org/) - a loose port of Lucene to C - might be worth a look.

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't know that it's a step in the right direction for my current project. As far as I can tell Lucy includes all the functionality of Lucene, including all the index-building infrastructure. It doesn't look like it would be any easier to strip that stuff out simply because it's in C instead of Java. Plus, Java is a more natural fit for Android apps than C (which would require using the NDK). But it's good to know about it. Thanks.